# How can I use the grandchild of one element to toggle a class on the grandchild of a previous element?

Tags: html, jquery, css

I've created a fiddle using the same html structure of a plugin I'm trying to edit. There are two 'grandparent' elements containing their ancestors, and I'm trying to use a button contained in one of them to toggle a class on an overlay contained in the other.

I've been trying various jQuery combinations, but so far nothing has worked. This is the one that I feel is most logical, can anyone point out where I'm going wrong?

It might be worth me mentioning that I don't have much flexibility in editing the html structure of the plugin, just the CSS and jQuery.

https://jsfiddle.net/71qdzr9j/4/

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {    
  
  $(".button").click(function() {
    $(this).parentsUntil(".lower-section").previous().find(".overlay").toggleClass("open");
  });
  
});
```

```css
.wrapper {
  position:relative;
  top:0;
  float:left;
  display:inline-block;
  width:275px;
  background:pink;
  margin-right:24px;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute !important;
  width: 100% !important;
  height: 100% !important;
  top: 0 !important;
  left: 0 !important;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5) !important;
  opacity: 0 !important;
}

.overlay.open {
  opacity:1;
}

.lower-section {
  position:relative;
}

.button {
  position:absolute;
  display:block;
  top:0;
  right:0;
  background:orange;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="wrapper">

  <a class="upper-section" href="">
    <div class="parent">
      <img class="child" width="275px" height="275px" src="https://i.ibb.co/vjsFfPq/Screenshot-2020-10-03-at-17-30-33.png"/>
      <span class="overlay"></span>
    </div>
  </a>

  <div class="lower-section">
    <div class="lower-section-inner">
      <div class="title">Autumn Trees</div>
      <div class="description">Mist rolling in over the horizion.</div>
      <span class="button">Button</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  
</div>

<div class="wrapper">

  <a class="upper-section" href="">
    <div class="parent">
      <img class="child" width="275px" height="275px" src="https://i.ibb.co/020Lc1f/Screenshot-2020-10-03-at-17-31-09.png"/>
      <span class="overlay"></span>
    </div>
  </a>

  <div class="lower-section">
    <div class="lower-section-inner">
      <div class="title">Ice patterns</div>
      <div class="description">Detail of a frozen landscape.</div>
      <span class="button">Button</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: So, you're trying to click the `.button` in the the `.lower-section` and target the `overlay` in the `upper-section` within the same `wrapper` element?

Comment: Yes, that's correct, the reason I included two wrappers elements is because whilst editing this plugin I often find solutions that seem to work work but I realise they affect every one of the elements when any of the buttons are clicked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are nearly there! You are **not** calling the right `jQuery` methods to `toggle` class `open` on. You need to use `parents()` and `prev()` method like this below:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {    
  $(".button").click(function() {
    $(this).parents(".lower-section").prev().find(".overlay").toggleClass("open");
    });
});
```

In addition you do not need to `important` at all. `jQuery` toggle method will do the job for you.

**Working Demo:**

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {    
  $(".button").click(function() {
    $(this).parents(".lower-section").prev().find(".overlay").toggleClass("open");
    });
});
```

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 275px;
  background: pink;
  margin-right: 24px;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute !important;
  width: 100% !important;
  height: 100% !important;
  top: 0 !important;
  left: 0 !important;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) !important;
  opacity: 0;
}

.overlay.open {
  opacity: 1;
}

.lower-section {
  position: relative;
}

.button {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: orange;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">

  <a class="upper-section" href="">
    <div class="parent">
      <img class="child" width="275px" height="275px" src="https://i.ibb.co/vjsFfPq/Screenshot-2020-10-03-at-17-30-33.png"/>
      <span class="overlay"></span>
    </div>
  </a>

  <div class="lower-section">
    <div class="lower-section-inner">
      <div class="title">Autumn Trees</div>
      <div class="description">Mist rolling in over the horizion.</div>
      <span class="button">Button</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  
</div>

<div class="wrapper">

  <a class="upper-section" href="">
    <div class="parent">
      <img class="child" width="275px" height="275px" src="https://i.ibb.co/020Lc1f/Screenshot-2020-10-03-at-17-31-09.png"/>
      <span class="overlay"></span>
    </div>
  </a>

  <div class="lower-section">
    <div class="lower-section-inner">
      <div class="title">Ice patterns</div>
      <div class="description">Detail of a frozen landscape.</div>
      <span class="button">Button</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  
</div>


<div class="wrapper">

  <a class="upper-section" href="">
    <div class="parent">
      <img class="child" width="275px" height="275px" src="https://i.ibb.co/vjsFfPq/Screenshot-2020-10-03-at-17-30-33.png"/>
      <span class="overlay"></span>
    </div>
  </a>

  <div class="lower-section">
    <div class="lower-section-inner">
      <div class="title">Autumn Trees</div>
      <div class="description">Mist rolling in over the horizion.</div>
      <span class="button">Button</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: @Jack1991 Glad to hear that. Let me know if i can help any further. Happy coding :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `closest()` in combination with `find()` to get to your class overlay:

```
  $(".button").click(function() {
    $(this).closest(".wrapper").find(".overlay").toggleClass("open");
  });
```

then you need to make sure, that the class "open" is actually executed, using !important

```
.wrapper .overlay.open {
  opacity:1 !important;
}
```

or,

in order to avoid use !important as last resource you can remove !important from your `.overlay{ opacity: 0 ;}`, then it's not needed to use !important in you .overlay.open anymore

see fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/8dq6Ljny/1/ with !important

https://jsfiddle.net/8dq6Ljny/2/ without !important

Comment: There is no need to use `important` at all.

Comment: @AlwaysHelping well you could remove !important from .overlay, then its not needed in .overlay.open

Comment: `!important` should be used as a last resort to solve issues - but not always. May be worth mentioning in your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Excited to post my first answer here :-)

Try not to use `!important` ever! It will cause a lot of mess especially if your code becomes larger.
I made my code in vanilla Javascript. JQuery is almost the same logic but just different function names.

My code edit is based on my understanding that you need to change overlay opacity of one picture if you clicked a button under the other picture.
However, if you wanted to change opacity of the same picture as the button, then just swap the `overlays[1]` and `overlays[0]` in the `if {...}` statements.

```js
  document.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    var titles = document.querySelectorAll(".title");
    var overlays = document.querySelectorAll(".overlay");

    var currentTitle = $(e.target).prev().prev().text();
    if (currentTitle === titles[0].innerText) {
      overlays[1].classList.toggle("open");
    }
    if (currentTitle === titles[1].innerText) {
      overlays[0].classList.toggle("open");
    }
  });
```

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 275px;
  background: pink;
  margin-right: 24px;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) !important;
  opacity: 0;
}

.open {
  opacity: 1;
}

.lower-section {
  position: relative;
}

.button {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: orange;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <title></title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css"></link>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!--//////////////////////////////////////////-->
    <div class="wrapper">
      <a class="upper-section" href="">
        <div class="parent">
          <img class="child" width="275px" height="275px" src="https://i.ibb.co/vjsFfPq/Screenshot-2020-10-03-at-17-30-33.png"/>
          <span class="overlay"></span>
        </div>
      </a>

      <div class="lower-section">
        <div class="lower-section-inner">
          <div class="title">Autumn Trees</div>
          <div class="description">Mist rolling in over the horizion.</div>
          <span class="button">Button</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--//////////////////////////////////////////-->
    <div class="wrapper">
      <a class="upper-section" href="">
        <div class="parent">
          <img class="child" width="275px" height="275px" src="https://i.ibb.co/020Lc1f/Screenshot-2020-10-03-at-17-31-09.png"/>
          <span class="overlay"></span>
        </div>
      </a>
      <div class="lower-section">
        <div class="lower-section-inner">
          <div class="title">Ice patterns</div>
          <div class="description">Detail of a frozen landscape.</div>
          <span class="button">Button</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're gonna kick yourself, but I think it's because your `opacity:1` in `.overlay` is being overridden but the `!important` on the `opacity:0` in `.overlay.open`.

Comment: I didn't see this, well spotted :) Unfortunately it doesn't seem to make a difference, because the class itself isn't being toggled. I think the problem lies within the jQuery.